# Calcular estadisticas trimestrales django

Tags: python, django

Tengo que mostrar diferentes estadisticas en un proyecto en django, hasta ahora funciona bien, cuando las calculo generales, pero necesito hacer cortes trimestrales, como podria hacerlo? les dejo la view.py

```
def inicio(request):
    plan_gral = jovenclub.objects.aggregate(sum=Sum('plan_gral'))//Calculo el plan GENERAl
    juridic_gral = ingresos.objects.aggregate(sum=Sum('juridico'))
    natural_gral = ingresos.objects.aggregate(sum=Sum('natural'))
    general = juridic_gral['sum']+natural_gral['sum'] //Calculo el ingreso juridico + el Natural
    porciento_general = general*100/plan_gral['sum']// calculo el % de Cumpliemiento
    ingreso = ingresos.objects.all()
```

En mi modelo poseo un campo de fecha
ademas en la vista tambien cree filtros a la base de datos por rango de fechas para separar los trimestes, ejemplo:

```
 # TRIMESTRES
  inicio_primertrimestre = datetime(2017, 1, 1)
  final_primertrimestre = datetime(2017, 3, 31)
  primer_trimestre=ingresos.objects.filter(fecha__range=(inicio_primertrimestre, final_primertrimestre))
```

en la vista tengo algo asi

```
 {% for datos in segundo_trimestre %}
<ul>
<li>{{datos.jovenclub}} {{ datos.fecha }} {{ datos.general }} </li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

cuando hago el render si se fijan si me hace la consulta por datos ingresados en ese rango de fechas... pero cuando intento ver el TOTAL de INgresos para esos meses... no muestra nada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podria calcular ese total, ya la funcion para el plan del año esta hecha

```
 plan_gral = jovenclub.objects.aggregate(sum=Sum('plan_gral'))
juridic_gral = ingresos.objects.aggregate(sum=Sum('juridico'))
natural_gral = ingresos.objects.aggregate(sum=Sum('natural'))
general = juridic_gral['sum']+natural_gral['sum']
porciento_general = general*100/plan_gral['sum']
```

seria adaptar esas funciones a los trimestres. Como?

Comment: Igual, agrega los filtros a tu query. La `view.py` tiene mal el formato, tal vez por eso no te funciona.

Comment: Listo, agrega los filtros de fechas para que expliques que es lo que tienes mal. O que obtienes vs. lo que esperas obtener.

Comment: listo ya edite la pregunta y corregi lo de la view.py, quiero hacer este calculo `plan_gral = jovenclub.objects.aggregate(sum=Sum('plan_gral'))//Calculo el plan GENERAl` pero solo en un rango de fechas

Comment: Y cuál es el resultado del queryset `primer_trimestre`. Es que así se hacen las consultas de rango de fechas. A menos que tengas algún error que no nos estés contando, tu pregunta ya está resuelta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pos gracias a los que me ayudaron... probando un poco encontre la respuesta.

```
segundo_trimestre=ingresos.objects.filter(fecha__range=(inicio_segundotrimestre, final_segundotrimestre))
segundo_trimestregral= segundo_trimestre.aggregate(sum=Sum('natural'))
return render_to_response('index.html', {'trimestregeneral':segundo_trimestregral['sum']}
```

y en el template asi `{{segundo_trimestregral}}`